# What is really wrong with this query please?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(parent_title, parent_fname, parent_sname) AS 'Parent'
CONCAT ('£1.50', sum(activity_price) AS Amount, COUNT(*) AS 'N.Activities'
FROM Activities A, Parent P, Child C, Register R
WHERE C.parent_id=P.parent_id AND C.child_id=R.child_id AND A.activity_id=R.activity_id
GROUP BY P.parent_id;
```

The Query browser says error is near the 'CONCAT(£1.50', sum(activity_price)....... FROM at line 2.

Comment: The CONCAT's argument list is never closed with a `)` in your query, as noted by Jon Seigel. On the other hand, it is not clear what particularly you are intending to concatenate there. Could there be an omission between `'£1.50',` and `sum(…`?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a MySQL expert, but it looks like:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(parent_title, parent_fname, parent_sname) AS 'Parent'
    CONCAT ('£1.50', sum(activity_price) AS Amount
```

should be:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(parent_title, parent_fname, parent_sname) AS 'Parent',
    CONCAT ('£1.50', sum(activity_price)) AS Amount
```

I added a comma after the first result column, and a trailing bracket to the `CONCAT` function.

While I have no idea if the latter concatenation is a valid operation, what I've suggested should fix the basic syntax errors.